# how to access yaml metadata from knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Does knitr know the value of YAML data e.g. title: or date: or some_custom_field: while it is compiling an rmarkdown doc with a YAML header?

I would like to be able to do this (pseudocode)

```
---
title: my title
---

The title of this document is `r knitrs_yaml_array("title")`
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is stored in `rmarkdown::metadata` as a list of the form `list(title = ...)`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify `rmarkdown::metadata` on the fly? Within a report constructed from modules/child documents , I would like to augment the abstract module-specific as the module is evaluated (or not).