# Adopting automatically argument options/details with knitr render depending if html or pdf is produced

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I realized that the layout of tables from knitr::kable() differs depending on the choice of making pdf or html. This can be 'solved' by choosing the most adopted choice for the argument format in knitr().
Many times I make html and pdf output of my .Rmd (different target audience - different habits) and there I have some difficulty for nice looking results for both of them with just a single .Rmd.

Ideally I want to work with just one Rmd file (for a given project ...) and adopt some details (eg the format="" argument in the function kable()) while running render() and avoid making 2 distinct versions of my Rmd (one for html and one for pdf).

My question is somehow related to [R - kable() used in .Rmd does not show output in notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775225/r-kable-used-in-rmd-does-not-show-output-in-notebook).
There it was suggested that using rmarkdown::metadata one can see what was written in the yaml header. In my yaml header I typically specify both the pdf and html.
So finally this does not help me, since the result of rmarkdown::metadata will always be the same, independently of I call rmarkdown::render("test1.Rmd", output_format='pdf_document') or rmarkdown::render("test1.Rmd", output_format='html_document').

1. Is there a way to know from within a chunk which output_format was chosen when calling rmarkdown::render() ?
2. Another option might be the yaml-header : Can I specify in the header which 'format' argument should be chosen with knitr ?
   Something like

   ```
   title: "my title"  
   header-includes: \usepackage{float}
   output:
     html_document: 
       toc: true
       knitr_format: html
     pdf_document:
       number_sections: no
       knitr_format: latex
   ```

This way I'd like to have R run either knitr::kable(xx, format="latex") or knitr::kable(xx, format="html") depending how rmarkdown::render() was called...

As mentioned, I looked at rmarkdown::metadata, but this doesn't allow knowing how render() was called.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `knitr::is_html_output` and/or `knitr::is_latex_output` to conditionally run your code depending on the output format:

````
---
title: "my title"  
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: no
  html_document: 
    toc: true
---

```{r}
format <- if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  "html"  
} else if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  "latex"
}

print(format)

knitr::kable(head(mtcars[1:4]), format = format)
```
````

[image]

[image]